# How can I retrieve in-app purchase data which is interrupted after payment completed with Cross Platform Native Plugins for unity?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase

I'm using Cross Platform Native Plugins' Billing API to do the In-App Purchase stuffs.

In Android, for example, in normal situation,
after a user complete the in-app purchase payment,
the activity would turns back to unity's activity in several seconds,
and then the purchase info would be available from callback.

But, if **the user has complete the payment, and close the app before callback has invoked, the purchase info would become lost ...**

I've tried restore purchases, but it is only for "Non-Consumable" purchases, the Consumable purchases still lost.

Is there any way to retrieve back the lost purchase info?Especially for "Consumable" purchases?

Answer (score 0):

Google has provide a [Google Play Developer API](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher) for solving this IAP order question, which contains [some ways](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/products/get) to retrieve any iap order information that has been created(even not successfully paid).

Working with play store's order management page, finally get enough information to solve the question of iap order lost.